# iOS - Show/hide UISplitViewController without using delegate methods with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, show-hide, uisplitviewcontroller

I'am trying to develop a multi-orientation app for iPad's. At landscape mode, the MasterViewController should always visible and I don't have any problem on that. But at portraid mode, I have to create a show/hide method. The main problem is, I cannot use delegate methods which are

**-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc**

and

**-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem**

Because my detailViewController is not a NavigationController and shouldn't
 be. Also detailViewController cannot have a NavigationItem. Let me explain why:

I want my all pages have a dashboard-like views at the bottom of the screen. So I never change detailViewController. At the top of the screen, I have a Navigation Controller embedded in a container view. So If you selected one of the MasterViewController's tableview items, the NavigationController's rootViewController is changing. That's why I cannot have a Navigation item in detailViewController.

These rootViewControllers have buttons which are passing their states to detailViewController wia a custom delegate method. And this method have to hide/show masterviewcontroller.

I don't want to create some custom views and/or animations or custom popover to achieve this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detail View Controller Does not need to be `UINavigationController` to be delegate to split view.

You can have set `DetailViewController` as delegate for the `UISplitViewController`. 
When the split view will hide the view (portrait) save the popover, which you can later show if needed.

Users might still show it without any button to - with swipe from left side of screen. If it's enough for your app then you don't need to implement the delegate methods.

```
// In App Delegate or Nib:
splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;




// In Detail View Controller :

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc {


    self.popoverController = pc;

    // Update ui 
    ...
 }


 - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

  self.popoverController = nil;
}


- (void)showMenu {
  [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect: ...]
}
```

Comment: Any UINavigationController is not the delegate of the SplitViewController. And that's the point. These methods force me to have a UINavigationController or a UINavigationItem on detailViewController, because these methods needs UIBarButtonItem, and my detailViewController is not able to have them.

Comment: Oooppss.. Sorry, I misunderstand you and you code. That's OK now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, delegate methods on UISplitView are quite confusing.